# How to save token obtained via login to a specific Extension in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, token

I have a web application in which I authenticate using tokens. I'm developing a plugin for this apps which are used to save items from different pages to the database. But this requires fetching users' categories in the plugin so that they can choose a category while saving. This also requires the token obtained during login to be used in the plugin.

So the question is basically, how can I save the token to be used in the plugin after I logged in my user into my web page?

Answer (score 0):

encode token using jwt-cookie and save in cookie
check this >>
https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/